# How to truncate a card

Tags: php, html, css

Here is a piece of my code.

```
<div class="thim-course-grid">
        <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <div class="lpr_course <?php echo 'course-grid-' . $columns; ?>">
                **<div class="course-item" onmouseover="hide_card('<?= get_the_ID()?>');" onmouseout="show_card('<?= get_the_ID()?>');">**
                    <div class="course-thumbnail" id="course-thumbnail-<?= get_the_ID()?>">
                        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_the_permalink( get_the_ID() ) ); ?>">
                            <?php echo thim_get_feature_image( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ), 'full', $thumb_w, $thumb_h, get_the_title() ); ?>
                        </a>
                        <?php do_action( 'thim_inner_thumbnail_course' ); ?>
                        <!-- <a class="course-readmore"
                           href="<?php echo esc_url( get_the_permalink( get_the_ID() ) ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html__( 'Read More', 'eduma' ); ?></a> -->
                    </div>

                    <div class="thim-course-content" id="thim-course-content-<?= get_the_ID()?>">
                        <?php learn_press_courses_loop_item_instructor(); 
                        the_title( sprintf( '<h2 class="course-title"><a href="%s" rel="bookmark">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ), '</a></h2>' );
                        ?>

                        <?php if ( class_exists( 'LP_Addon_Coming_Soon_Courses_Preload' ) && learn_press_is_coming_soon( get_the_ID() ) ): ?>
                            <div class="message message-warning learn-press-message coming-soon-message">
                                <?php esc_html_e( 'Coming soon', 'eduma' ) ?>
                            </div>
                        <?php else: ?>
                            <div class="course-meta">
                                <?php learn_press_courses_loop_item_instructor(); ?>
                                <?php thim_course_ratings(); ?>
                                <?php learn_press_courses_loop_item_students(); ?>
                                <?php thim_course_ratings_count(); ?>
                                <?php learn_press_courses_loop_item_price(); ?>
                            </div>

                            <?php learn_press_courses_loop_item_price(); ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>

                        <div class="course-readmore">
                            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink() ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Read More', 'eduma' ); ?></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php
        endwhile;
        ?>
    </div>
```

On the 4th line, I wanted to truncate the course maps on mouse over, so that all the part of the map at the bottom of the image disappears, only to reappear when there is no more flyover. The result obtained is different from what I wanted.

I put the link to the site to see: [www.formatine.com](http://www.formatine.com)

And here is the JS part that I added as well.

```js
function hide_card(id) {
    document.getElementById('thim-course-content-'+id).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('course-thumbnail-'+id).innerHTML = "<?= wp_oembed_get( $media_intro ) ?>";

  }

  function show_card(id) {
    document.getElementById('thim-course-content-'+id).style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('course-thumbnail-'+id).style.display = 'block';
  }
```

Do you have an idea for me please? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use "display: none" because once it has it, the element "disappears".

It is better for you, to then, if you want to include a video instead of the card, for example, do it by having both, one behind the other by default, if you "mouseover" display the code INSIDE of one, and on "mouseout", display the other.

```
    <div class="mycard">
        <div class="myinfoforthevideo"></div>
        <div class="myvideo"></div>
    </div>
```

You controll the events on `mycard` class, and hide `myinfoforthevideo` by default, on "mouseover", hide it and show then `myvideo`, and on "mouseout" hide `myvideo` and show `myinfoforthevideo`

You're hidding everything so now since its a `width: 0/height: 0` let's say, you don't have any place to do the `mouseover` now.

Extra:
You can try `flip cards` as another option, like this:

https://codepen.io/Aoyue/pen/pLJqgE